# intermediates folder generated by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I have a fairly large viewpager app that I want to restyle to Material Design.  I used Android Studio to create a brand new app that doesn't do anything other than demonstrate a working viewpager, tabs, and Material Design.  The new app has a look that is exactly  what I want.

Examining the new app I see that AS generated a boat load of useful resource code in the intermediates directory that enabled Material Design.  So AS first generated the src/ code according to my choices in the "new project" process and then something in that code caused the build process to generate all of this useful Material Design support code.

For instance, the generated app has a styles xml that begins with...

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

If you ctrl-b on DarkActionBar it jumps to a huge file . . .

```
C:\Users\Gary\AndroidstudioProjects\MDShell\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.3.0\res\values\values.xml
```

that contains the definition.  I want the build process to do that same generation for my app.

EDIT : This is the answer to my question...
Once I included the following two lines in the gradle, everything I needed got generated in my app

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

Comment: Android Studio is generating tons of code that is useful for the support of Material Design.  I'm asking what is it that caused AS to do this useful generation as I would like for this to occur in my app which I am converting to Material Design.  What the hell is off - topic about that in an Android Developers forum???

Comment: I don't see why so many down votes. This question and @CommonsWare answer saved me quite a few hours.

Answer (score 5):

> I googled around for an hour or so but can find no documentation on how this directory gets built and included in the new project.

Everything in the `build/` directory, such as `build/intermediates/`, is output of the build process.

> I could probably copy it into my project

If "it" is `build/intermediates/`, please do not copy it. You are welcome to copy things from your `src/` tree between projects, as well as values from your `build.gradle` file (e.g., dependencies).

> Does anyone know where the docs regarding this might be?

There is no comprehensive set of documentation for what appears in `build/`, in part because depends on a dizzying array of environmental factors (what dependencies do you have? are you using JNI? are you employing annotation processors?).

Generally speaking, developers do not often look in `build/`.

Comment: I should have asked "what is it that is causing AS to generate all of these useful resources.  AS put something into the src/ or gradle that caused the build to generate all of this.

Comment: @DeanBlakely: That's just part of the standard build process with Gradle and the Android build tools. The Android-specific stuff comes from the Android Plugin for Gradle (e.g., `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`). Some aspects of it come from stock Gradle tasks that the Android Plugin for Gradle connects to.